# MFC: Changing from CDialog to CWnd now the CStatusBar doesn't show?

Tags: winapi, mfc, statusbar

To work around a problem with a `CDialog` being minimized when main window was minimized I decided to try using a `CWnd` instead.  That works but now the `CStatusBar` doesn't show?  What might I be missing or is there some requirement for it to show?

The new `CWnd` is created like this:

```
CString classname=AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, 0, 0,  LoadIcon(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDR_MAINFRAME)));
m_pDlgNowACWnd->CreateEx(0, classname, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), NULL, 0)
```

The initialization in `OnInitDialog()` now being `OnCreate()` does the nroaml `m_StatusBar.Create(this)` then initializes it further with:

```
EnableDynamicLayout(FALSE);

// set our own height so we can scale
CStatusBarCtrl &statusctrl=m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl();
statusctrl.SetMinHeight(g_DPIHelper.Scale(20));

m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, _countof(indicators));

m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo (0, ID_SEPARATOR, SBPS_NORMAL|SBPS_STRETCH, 0); 
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo (sliderPane, ID_SEPARATOR, SBPS_NORMAL, g_DPIHelper.Scale(128)); 
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo (textPane, ID_SEPARATOR, SBPS_NORMAL|SBPS_POPOUT, g_DPIHelper.Scale(30)); 
// add this to workaround the GetSystemMatrix() issue above.
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo (STATUSBARspacerPane, ID_SEPARATOR, SBPS_NORMAL, 25); 

// this is needed to calc location and size of bar
RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, IDC_VIEW_ACHILDCWND);

EnableDynamicLayout();

auto pdlmanager=GetDynamicLayout();
if (pdlmanager) {
  if (pdlmanager->Create(this)) {
    pdlmanager->AddItem(m_CWndView.GetSafeHwnd(), CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
    pdlmanager->AddItem(m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd(), CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100),   CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
  }
}
```

It's a status bar with a slider on it and some text.

The main `CDialog` now `CWnd` has two children a `CWnd` and a `CStatusBar`.  The initial size of the dialog/window is 0, but then is resized to correct size when the dialog/window will be shown.

Any idea what I may be missing or doing wrong on converting from `CDialog` to a `CWnd` ?

Everything else works, just the `CStatusBar` not showing?

Thanks.

Update:

It appears to be the `CStatusBar` height being zero.  I did a test of creating the `CWnd` being `CRect(0, 0, 10, 50)` instead of all zeros and the `CStatusBar` shows (although with a height of 11 which is much shorter than it should be).  It seems the `statusctrl.SetMinHeight(g_DPIHelper.Scale(20))` call doesn't work when using `CWnd`?  The resizing takes place in `RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, IDC_VIEW_ACHILDCWND);` I set a breakpoint on `CStatusBar::OnSize()` and noticed when a `CDialog` it had the correct size but not with `CWnd`(had zero originally now 11 with using a height of 50 on the `CWnd` `Create()`).

Comment: Note that CDialog often uses dialog units for measurements, while almost everything else uses pixels.  They're very different.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want to minimise a dialog and the parent dialog why do you need to do all of this work?

Comment: i wanted them separate, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the height of the `CStatusBar` won't change once created and calculated during `OnCreate()` the size of the created `CWnd` needs to be tall enough for the desired `CStatusBar` minimum height.   So instead of this:

```
m_pDlgNowACWnd->CreateEx(0, classname, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), NULL, 0);
```

Do this:

```
CRect rccreate(0, 0, 0, MYDLG_STATUSBAR_MINHEIGHT);
CalcWindowRect(&rccreate);
m_pDlgNowACWnd->CreateEx(0, classname, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, rccreate, NULL, 0);
```